# Prove that a function is continuous at $x = x_{0}$ using the $\delta - \epsilon$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Prove that $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{ if } x\in \mathbb{Q}^{c} \end{cases}$ is continuous at $0$

$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists  \delta = ?$ such that

$|x - 0| < \delta$, then

case $1$) if $x$ is rational, then $|f(x) - f(0)| = x^2 < \delta^2$, so take $\delta = \sqrt\epsilon$.

case $2$) if $x$ is irrational, then $|f(x) - f(0)| = 0 < \delta$? What should the $\delta$ be in this case?

Comment: $\delta$ can be any positive real number.. Don't you hope so?

Comment: So $\delta$ can be any positive real number for the second case. Then overall, I would take $\delta = min \left \{ \sqrt \epsilon, \mathbb{R} \right \}$?

Comment: yes, you can take that...

Comment: Prof. showed an similar in class example, where there were 2 cases (rational and irrational). We found 2 $\delta$s, one for each case. And overall we chose the smaller $\delta$.

Comment: Just a side-note, you could also use the Squeeze theorem with the functions $f_1(x):=x^2$ and $f_2(x):=0$, although this ends up being the same proof essentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|x-0| = |x| \leq \delta$ then $$|f(x) - f(0) | = |f(x)| \leq x^2 \leq \delta^2 $$So if $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ $$|f(x) - f(0) | \leq \epsilon$$Thus $f$ is continous in $0$.